# Winzip Self Extracting exe would end abruptly without showing "All Done" in cmd

Tags: batch-file, winzip, self-extracting

I have got a batch script that ends with the following:

```
TITLE ALL DONE. You can close this window
ECHO.
ECHO ALL DONE. You can close this window
ECHO.
Pause
EXIT
```

it works fine when i run just the bat file (see below)

All Done! You can close this window.
Press any key to continue . . .

But when i create a self extracting exe out of the same bat script it wouldn't show this window after the execution and would just exit without any proper message.

Since the script works fine by itself, i am a bit lost on what could be causing this? How could i make the self extracting exe to show that window and prompt the user to close it like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the content of the executable, if your including other files to your archive be sure the program you run after extraction is your batch file.

If your only including that file i suggest you use [BatToExe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php)

much more efficient way to build it, also it supports commandline, including other files, product info, admin manifest etc